Github Pages for Vite React project remains blank - despite npm run build and static workflows
My Github Page is blank after deploying a repo: https://jlimsy.github.io/retrogram/
Repo here: https://github.com/jlimsy/retrogram
I was following the documentation on vite's website: https://vite.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages:
Did an npm run build and npm run preview: site shows up fine
Project folder and vite.config file
This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file that I copied off the Vite instructions:
image: node:16.5.0
pages:
  stage: deploy
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
      prefix: npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cp -a dist/. public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

& also updated the github static workflow with .yml file in Vite's documentation.
Am I missing other commands? If I am, why are they not in the documentation? :'(
